# Multiple payments at once?

Tags: paypal

I tried asking this on the normal PayPal forums, but they suggested asking it here.

I'm working on a site, where people will be able to sell their goods. The money goes direct to them, and we then just invoice the seller at the end of the month (for their "fee").

My question - is it possible to have multiple amounts paid for in one go (they could also be in different currencies, just FYI). I basically want to get something like eBay has (where you can add multiple items to the cart, and then pay for them all at once)

If not, I guess I'll have to stick with a more basic system of letting them add to the cart, and then at the final stage - give them different buttons for each person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/) platform.  Look into parallel and chained payments.

Comment: I've just been having a look into this, and I'm a bit confused. I can't find any Perl examples (pretty much every language APART from Perl???). Is there anyone who can point me to some info on how to get the API key (from what I read up, it sounds like I need a payflow account.. which I have to pay for?)

Comment: You don't need Pro (PayFlow) for Adaptive Payments.  You can get an API key by logging in to your [PayPal developer account](http://developer.paypal.com), then go into Applications, and then click My Apps on the left.  Then you'll see both REST and Classic Apps.  You want Classic.  Create a new app there and that will give you a live App Key once approved.

Comment: Man, the paypal docs are shocking :( I've created an account in my PayPal account (in **Profile >My Selling Preferences > API access**), and then made a sandbox account at developer.paypal.com. Then I'm trying a test script, sending to 'https://svcs.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay' (I've tried sandbox as well).. yet I always get this error (520003):

Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect.

I'm guessing its cos I'm not passing my app-id ... but where on earth is that?

Comment: Ok - I found where you get it - for anyone else who comes across it, you need to use they're global app-id for sandbox: **APP-80W284485P519543T** . However, I'm still the "Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect." error, when though the details are the same as I'm seeing in my profile (do I maybe need to get the details from a developer account, and not the main account I'm using? .. it seems a bit all over the place :/)

Comment: Ah ha - finally got it! (btw, why can't you do full replies, instead of having to do all these smaller replies??). For anyone else having the same problem as me - first of all you need to create a "Business" account at developer.paypal.com. Once you've done that, login to the Sandbox site with those new credentials. Then you would go to **Profile > My Selling Preferences > API access**, and get the logins there (just for sandbox). Hopefully that helps someone out!